# Does Mongoose always use only one connection instance per request created in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Why does Mongoose always use only one connection instance per request created in nodejs?

```
const mongo_uri = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_PWD}@${process.env.MONGO_URL}/${process.env.MONGO_DB}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;
mongoose.connect(mongo_uri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});
const serverStatus = () => {
    return [{
        mongoose: {
            state: 'up',
            dbState: mongoose.STATES[mongoose.connection.readyState]
        }
    }]
};
//  Plug into middleware.
app.use('/healthcheck', require('express-healthcheck')({
    healthy: serverStatus
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose uses the connection made by `mongoose.connect()` as a default, however you can have multiple connections:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections

As to why, its so that you can use it in mutliple scripts without needing to pass a connection around.